# How to use multi word alias name in keytool genkeypair command?

Tags: keytool

I can't use an alias with multiple words because of an error.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore node1.keystore -alias "foo bar" \
-dname "CN=node1.example.com,O=Hadoop" -keyalg RSA \
-keysize 2048 -storepass changeme -keypass changeme
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Illegal option:  bar
```

How can I use an alias with multiple words?

Comment: What OS and command line tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't.

It seems that only single word aliases are supported. This is probably a limitation in the KeyStore implementation.

Comment: That's not true.  If you look at the keytool code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhFTs.png), it reads the alias entered in the command line as-is, without any modification. OP seems to be using a two-word value between double quotes, Maybe the command line tool he is using needs a different way to escape the space, like a single quote or a backslash or escaping it twice. It depends on the OS and the command line tool he is using. But both the keytool and the KeyStore do support spaces in alias.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for investigating.